# Automation Testing tool for Ipad and safari using Java

Tags: testing, cross-browser, automation, integration-testing, ui-automation

I am a new to testing mobile applications and I am looking for a testing tool like selenium Ide  which allow me to record and play my test cases without developing any (or less) source code for ipad and safari using JAVA.

Can you help me with that, please?

Any Paid or unpaid tool is fine ....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to look outside Java, I'd encourage you to look at [Telerik's Test Studio for iOS](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing.aspx). (Disclosure: I work for Telerik)

Test Studio for iOS enables you to record and play back functional tests for iOS devices. You can automate native iOS applications (UIKit), web applications, or hybrid/mixed-mode. We've just released in Beta, and should be releasing our official v1 in June.